# Minimax algorithm seems stuck in infinite loop, please help!

Tags: python

2 players works fine but I can't debug the minimax algorithm, it just keeps going..
sorry that the code is messy

````
import random

# board in nested list
board = [[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']]

# draws the board
def boarddraw(board):
    print("\t  1   2   3   4   5   6   7")
    print("\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")
    print("\t| "+board[0][0]+" | "+board[0][1]+" | "+board[0][2]+" | "+board[0][3]+" | "+board[0][4]+" | "+board[0][5]+" | "+board[0][6]+" |")
    print("\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")
    print("\t| "+board[1][0]+" | "+board[1][1]+" | "+board[1][2]+" | "+board[1][3]+" | "+board[1][4]+" | "+board[1][5]+" | "+board[1][6]+" |")
    print("\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")
    print("\t| "+board[2][0]+" | "+board[2][1]+" | "+board[2][2]+" | "+board[2][3]+" | "+board[2][4]+" | "+board[2][5]+" | "+board[2][6]+" |")
    print("\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")
    print("\t| "+board[3][0]+" | "+board[3][1]+" | "+board[3][2]+" | "+board[3][3]+" | "+board[3][4]+" | "+board[3][5]+" | "+board[3][6]+" |")
    print("\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")
    print("\t| "+board[4][0]+" | "+board[4][1]+" | "+board[4][2]+" | "+board[4][3]+" | "+board[4][4]+" | "+board[4][5]+" | "+board[4][6]+" |")
    print("\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")
    print("\t| "+board[5][0]+" | "+board[5][1]+" | "+board[5][2]+" | "+board[5][3]+" | "+board[5][4]+" | "+board[5][5]+" | "+board[5][6]+" |")
    print("\t+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")

# randomizer to determine who starts
def start(starter = ['p1','p2']):
    starter = random.choice(starter)
    return starter

# player move
def pmove(valid = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]):
    pmove = 0
    while pmove not in valid:
        try:
            pmove = int(input(player+ ", please select which column you want to drop your piece("+piece+"): (1 - 7): "))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return pmove

# runs several fuctions to check boardstate for wins for player
def checkwin(board):
    if winhorizontal(board):
        return True
    elif winvertical(board):
        return True
    elif windiagonala(board):
        return True
    elif windiagonalb(board):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# runs checkwin functions and displays winner
def winner():
    if checkwin(board):
        boarddraw(board)
        print("\n"+player+" won!!!")
        return True
    else:
        return False

# checks if board is full, if so, the game is a draw
def free(board):
    if any(' ' in space for space in board):
        return True
    else:
        print("draw")
        return False

# function to check which is the lowest row of the column that is free
def drop(pmove):
    i = 0
    if board[i][pmove-1] != ' ':
        return False
    else:
        while board[i][pmove-1] == ' ':
            if i == 5:
               board[i][pmove-1] = piece
               return True
            i += 1
        board[i-1][pmove-1] = piece
        return True

# Horizontal check
def winhorizontal(board):
    for column in range(6):
        for row in range(4):

            if board[column][row] + board[column][row+1] + board[column][row+2] + board[column][row+3] == 4 * piece:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# Vertical check
def winvertical(board):    
    for column in range(3):
        for row in range(7):
            if board[column][row] + board[column+1][row] + board[column+2][row] + board[column+3][row] == 4 * piece:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# diagonal check a 
def windiagonala(board):    
    for column in range(3):
        for row in range(4):
            if board[column][row] + board[column+1][row+1] + board[column+2][row+2] + board[column+3][row+3] == 4 * piece:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# diagonal check b
def windiagonalb(board):
    for column in range(3,6):
        for row in range(4):
            if board[column][row] + board[column-1][row+1] + board[column-2][row+2] + board[column-3][row+3] == 4 * piece:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# runs checkwin functions and displays winner 
def winner1():
    if checkwin1(board):
        print("won")
        return True
    else:
        return False

# runs checkwin functions and displays winner
def winner2():
    if checkwin2(board):
        print("lost")
        return True
    else:
        return False

def checkwin1(board):
    if winhorizontal1(board):
        return True
    elif winvertical1(board):
        return True
    elif windiagonala1(board):
        return True
    elif windiagonalb1(board):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def checkwin2(board):
    if winhorizontal2(board):
        return True
    elif winvertical2(board):
        return True
    elif windiagonala2(board):
        return True
    elif windiagonalb2(board):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Horizontal check AI1
def winhorizontal1(board):
    for column in range(6):
        for row in range(4):

            if board[column][row] + board[column][row+1] + board[column][row+2] + board[column][row+3] == 4 * dr:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# Vertical check AI1
def winvertical1(board):    
    for column in range(3):
        for row in range(7):
            if board[column][row] + board[column+1][row] + board[column+2][row] + board[column+3][row] == 4 * dr:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# diagonal check a AI1
def windiagonala1(board):    
    for column in range(3):
        for row in range(4):
            if board[column][row] + board[column+1][row+1] + board[column+2][row+2] + board[column+3][row+3] == 4 * dr:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# diagonal check b AI1
def windiagonalb1(board):
    for column in range(3,6):
        for row in range(4):
            if board[column][row] + board[column-1][row+1] + board[column-2][row+2] + board[column-3][row+3] == 4 * dr:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# Horizontal check AI2
def winhorizontal2(board):
    for column in range(6):
        for row in range(4):

            if board[column][row] + board[column][row+1] + board[column][row+2] + board[column][row+3] == 4 * pl:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# Vertical check AI2
def winvertical2(board):    
    for column in range(3):
        for row in range(7):
            if board[column][row] + board[column+1][row] + board[column+2][row] + board[column+3][row] == 4 * pl:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# diagonal check a AI2
def windiagonala2(board):    
    for column in range(3):
        for row in range(4):
            if board[column][row] + board[column+1][row+1] + board[column+2][row+2] + board[column+3][row+3] == 4 * pl:
                return True
            else:
                continue
# diagonal check b AI2
def windiagonalb2(board):
    for column in range(3,6):
        for row in range(4):
            if board[column][row] + board[column-1][row+1] + board[column-2][row+2] + board[column-3][row+3] == 4 * pl:
                return True
            else:
                continue

def compmove():
    bestscore = -10000                               
    bestmove = 0                                    
    for move in range(7):                                
            if board[0][move] == ' ':                              
                j = 0
                while board[j][move] == ' ':
                    if j == 5:
                        board[j][move] = dr
                        score = deepretard(board, 0, False) 
                        board[j][move] = ' '                                 
                        if score > bestscore:                          
                            bestscore = score
                            bestmove = move
                            return bestscore
                    j += 1
                board[j-1][move] = dr
                score = deepretard(board, 0, False) 
                board[j-1][move] = ' '
    if score > bestscore:                          
        bestscore = score
        print(bestscore)                   
        bestmove = move + 1                    
                      
    return bestmove

def deepretard(board, treedepth, max):
    if winner1():                   
        return 1                   
    elif winner2():                 
        return -1                   
    elif not free(board):                   
        return 0                    
    if max:                       
        bestscore = -10000           
        for move in range(7):                                 
            if board[0][move] == ' ':                              
                i = 0
                while board[i][move] == ' ':
                    if i == 5:
                        board[i][move] = dr
                        score = deepretard(board, treedepth + 1, False) 
                        board[i][move] = ' '                                 
                        if score > bestscore:                          
                            bestscore = score
                            return bestscore
                    i += 1
                board[i-1][move] = dr
                score = deepretard(board, treedepth + 1, False) 
                board[i-1][move] = ' '                                 
        if score > bestscore:                          
            bestscore = score                            
        return bestscore
    else:
        bestscore = 10000                                         
        for move in range(7):                                
            if board[0][move] == ' ':                              
                i = 0
                while board[i][move] == ' ':
                    if i == 5:
                        board[i][move] = pl
                        score = deepretard(board, treedepth + 1, True) 
                        board[i][move] = ' '                                 
                        if score < bestscore:                          
                            bestscore = score
                            return bestscore
                    i += 1
                board[i-1][move] = pl
                score = deepretard(board, treedepth + 1, True) 
                board[i-1][move] = ' '                                 
        if score < bestscore:                          
            bestscore = score 
        return bestscore

# Game start
print("""
_________                                     __      _____  
\_   ___ \  ____   ____   ____   ____   _____/  |_   /  |  | 
/    \  \/ /  _ \ /    \ /    \_/ __ \_/ ___\   __\ /   |  |_
\     \___(  <_> )   |  \   |  \  ___/\  \___|  |  /    ^   /
 \______  /\____/|___|  /___|  /\___  >\___  >__|  \____   | 
        \/            \/     \/     \/     \/           |__| 
\t\t\t\t\t   By Jeroen Penders
 """)
print("Welcome to Connect 4 version 1.1\n")
print("AI is coming soon, for now this is only a 2 player game, enjoy!\n")
print("Enter 1 to play against DeepRetard AI")
print("Enter 2 to play a 2 player game")
playercount = int(input("Enter 1 or 2: "))
if playercount == 2:
    name1 = input("Player 1 please enter your name: ")
    name2 = input("Player 2 please enter your name: ")
    print("\nHello, "+name1+" and "+name2+"!\n" )
    input("Please press enter to see who begins\n")
    starter = start()
    if starter == 'p1':
        player1 = name1
        player2 = name2
        print(name1+" begins!\n")
        input("Press enter to begin...")
    else:
        player2 = name1
        player1 = name2
        print(name2+" begins!\n")
        input("Press enter to begin...")
    while free(board):
        player = player1
        piece = 'X'
        boarddraw(board)
        p1move = pmove()
        while not drop(p1move):
            boarddraw(board)
            print("Column is full...")
            p1move = pmove()
        if winner():
            exit()
        player = player2
        piece = 'O'
        boarddraw(board)
        p2move = pmove()
        while not drop(p2move):
            boarddraw(board)
            print("Column is full...")
            p2move = pmove()
        if winner():
            exit()

    # only displayed if board is full
    boarddraw(board)
    print("Board is full, it's a draw...")

else:
    name1 = input("Please enter your name: ")
    name2 = "DeepRetard"
    print("\nHello, "+name1+"! So you think you can defeat DeepRetard?")
    input("Press enter to see who begins")
    starter = start()
    if starter == 'p1':
        player1 = name1
        player2 = name2
        print(name1+" begins!\n")
        input("Press enter to begin...")
        piece = 'X'
        pl = 'X'
        dr = 'O'
        player = player1
        boarddraw(board)
        p1move = pmove()
        while not drop(p1move):
            boarddraw(board)
            print("Column is full...")
            p1move = pmove()
        if not free(board):
            print("The game is a draw...")
            exit()
        if winner():
            exit()
        player = player2
        compm = compmove()
        p2move = pmove(compm)
        if winner():
            exit()

    else:
        player2 = name1
        player1 = name2
        print(name2+" begins!\n")
        input("Press enter to begin...")
        dr = 'X'
        pl = 'O'
        player = player1
        boarddraw(board)
        compm = compmove()
        p2move = pmove(compm)
        while not drop(p1move):
            boarddraw(board)
            print("Column is full...")
            p1move = pmove()
        if not free(board):
            print("The game is a draw...")
            exit()
        if winner():
            exit()
        player = player2
        boarddraw(board)
        p1move = pmove()
        while not drop(p1move):
            boarddraw(board)
            print("Column is full...")
            p1move = pmove()
        if not free(board):
            print("The game is a draw...")
            exit()
        if winner():
            exit()
```
````

Comment: It looks to me like your algorithm is set to explore the game tree exhaustively, without ever falling back on a heuristic. So, checking all 7 possible moves, then all 7 possible replies to each of those, then all 7 possible replies to each of those... until there are no more legal moves to check. Since Connect 4 has something like 4.5 trillion game states, and your code has no memoization to avoid re-checking the equivalent states from multiple directions, you might not be in an "infinite" loop, just  busy checking more possibilities than can be explored in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I will look into that! 
I'm just a beginner but making the minimax algorithm more efficient is definitely something I want to expore!

Comment: Try stopping at a tree depth of 4 or so, and see if that is enough that your algorithm terminates in a reasonable time. If so, then it's probably not an infinite loop, just biting off more computation than you can chew, and you can update your question to ask for help writing a fallback heuristic to handle cases beyond your exploration horizon.